# Find a $\tau(6n)$, if $\tau (2n)=28$ and $\tau (3n)=30$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Find a $\tau(6n)$, such that $\tau (2n)=28$ and $\tau (3n)=30$.

Since $n\in \mathbb N$ $n=p_1^{\alpha_1} \cdot p_2^{\alpha_2} \cdot p_3^{\alpha_3}\cdots p_n^{\alpha_n}$, then $2n=p_1^{\alpha_1+1} \cdot p_2^{\alpha_2} \cdot p_3^{\alpha_3}\cdots p_n^{\alpha_n}, p_1=2$,  $3n=p_1^{\alpha_1} \cdot p_2^{\alpha_2+1} \cdot p_3^{\alpha_3}\cdots p_n^{\alpha_n}, p_2=3$,

If $gcd(n,3)=1$ and $gcd(n,2)=1$ then $\tau (2n)=\tau (2) \tau (n)=28$ and $\tau (3n)=\tau (3)\tau (n)=30$ then $\tau(n)=14\not =15= \tau (n)$

then $\tau (2n)=(2+\alpha_1)(1+\alpha_2)\ldots(1+\alpha_n)=28=2\cdot 2 \cdot 7=2\cdot 14$ and $\tau (3n)=(1+\alpha_1)(2+\alpha_2)\ldots(1+\alpha_n)=30=2\cdot 2 \cdot 3=5\cdot 6$, since $2+\alpha_1 >2$ and $2+\alpha_2>2$ then, from first equation $2+\alpha_1=7$ or $2+\alpha_1=14$, so $\alpha_1=5$ or $\alpha_1=12$ because of other equation we need $\alpha_1=5$ and then $6(2+\alpha_2)=30$, so $\alpha_2=3$.

Then  $\tau(6n)=(2+\alpha_1)(2+\alpha_2)=(2+5)(2+3)=35$

Is this ok?

Comment: It is not clear why should $2+α_1>2$  and $2+α_2>2$? What if $\gcd(n,2)=1$?

Comment: because for smallest number $\alpha_1=1$ then $2+\alpha_1=3$ so for every number $2+\alpha_1>2$

Comment: I mean, $\tau$ is a multiplicative function, thus if $\gcd(n,3)=1$ and $\gcd(n,2)=1$ then $\tau(2n)=\tau(2)\tau(n)=28$ and $\tau(3n)=\tau(3)\tau(n)=30$ then $\tau(n)=14\ne 15=\tau(n)$. So, either $\gcd(n,2)>1$ or $\gcd(n,3)>1$, **or**, not **and**. You need to show that **and** applies. Only **after** that you can use $2+α_1>2$  **and** $2+α_2>2$ ...

Comment: With $α_1=1$ you just assumed that $2 \mid n$, but this is not given ...

Comment: sorry I know for that but I did not write  thank you

Comment: Oh, so you are hiding important input information? :) ... Update the question then.